# Selecting fields from JSON output

Tags: python

Using Python, how can i extract the field `id` to a variable? Basicaly, i to transform this:

```
{
    "accountWide": true,
    "criteria": [
        {
            "description": "some description",
            "id": 7553,
            "max": 1,
            "orderIndex": 0
        }
     ]
}
```

to something like

```
print "Description is: " + description
print "ID is: " + id
print "Max value is : " + max
```

Comment: You could have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/json.html Everything can be found there.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Assume you stored that dictionary in a variable called values. To get `id` in to a variable, do:

```
idValue = values['criteria'][0]['id']
```

If that json is in a file, do the following to load it:

```
import json
jsonFile = open('your_filename.json', 'r')
values = json.load(jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()
```

If that json is from a URL, do the following to load it:

```
import urllib, json
f = urllib.urlopen("http://domain/path/jsonPage")
values = json.load(f)
f.close()
```

To print ALL of the criteria, you could:

```
for criteria in values['criteria']:
    for key, value in criteria.iteritems():
        print key, 'is:', value
    print ''
```

Comment: Hi, in fact it is an http output. i will try to convert your example to parse the output from the website.

Comment: @Thales See the example section of: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#examples  Take the value returned by `urllib.urlopen` and pass that to `json.load` in place of `jsonFile` my example above.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you are dealing with a JSON-string in the input, you can parse it using the `json` package, see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

In the specific example you posted you would need

```
x = json.loads("""{
 "accountWide": true,
 "criteria": [
     {
         "description": "some description",
         "id": 7553,
         "max": 1,
         "orderIndex": 0
     }
  ]
 }""")
description = x['criteria'][0]['description']
id = x['criteria'][0]['id']
max = x['criteria'][0]['max']
```

Comment: how about accessing all descriptions (or ids) across all higher-level entities?