# Cloudflare API cut JSON response

Tags: json, bash, curl, awk, sed

I appear to be struggling with cutting the JSON responses from [CloudFlare's API](https://api.cloudflare.com/).

when I CURL the https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/xxxx/settings URL it returns all settings for the zone of my domain in a JSON response such as:

```
        "editable": true,
        "id": "server_side_exclude",
        "modified_on": null,
        "value": "on"
    },
    {
        "editable": false,
        "id": "sha1_support",
        "modified_on": null,
        "value": "off"
    },
    {
        "editable": false,
        "id": "sort_query_string_for_cache",
        "modified_on": null,
        "value": "off"
    },
    {
        "certificate_status": "active",
        "editable": true,
        "id": "ssl",
        "modified_on": "2016-05-18T14:38:45.665403Z",
        "value": "flexible"
```

This is because I am of course cutting it by piping the curl to **python -m json.tool**. What I am trying to achieve is basically print everything as for example:

```
server_side_exclude = on
sha1_support = off
sort_query_string_for_cache = off
```

( the ID = the value ). I have attempted to store the IDs and values in separate variables as for example:

```
IDs=$(curl https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/xxxx/settings | python -m json.tool | grep id)
Values=$(curl https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/xxxx/settings | python -m json.tool | grep value)
```

and then printing them next to each other for example with:

```
echo "$IDs = $Values"
```

but the empty spaces appear to cause difficulties. I have also tried to cut the reply by using **awk** and **sed** but am not that familiar with the tools and had no success as well.

Could someone more familiar with cutting text assist me please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934699/selecting-fields-from-json-output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse json :

```
curl https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/xxxx/settings | \
    jq '.result | map({(.id):.value}) | add'
```

It gives :

```
{
  "always_online": "on",
  "server_side_exclude": "on",
  "sha1_support": "off",
  "sort_query_string_for_cache": "off",
  "ssl": "flexible"
}
```

If you want to extract the value of one field, for `server_side_exclude` :

```
curl https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/xxxx/settings | \
    jq -r '.result | map({(.id):.value}) | add | .server_side_exclude'
```

The input I used for the parsing is [here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/636dbb29dc8a4f6838efa5fdd665608e)

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you mate, I have been testing around with **jq** for the past hour and a half and could not figure out the correct syntax. Thank you so much, this completely solves my issue.