# Get OneNote timestamps through the API

Tags: python, rest, onenote, onenote-api

Is there a way to get the timestamps for content in a OneNote page through the OneNote API, or another way? I have been using the API to get the html content and metadata of my pages, however I have not found a way to get the timestamps. I want to get these so I can see an edit history. These exist in OneNote as they show up when you highlight text and right click on it, as shown: OneNote Timestamp. Basically is there anyway to export this information? Ideally this would be in Python, but I'm not picky.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for the edit history of a page, it seems like your best bet is to use the "lastModifiedDateTime" field in Microsoft's responses to GET /me/onenote/pages/{id}.

Here is a sample response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 312

{
  "title": "title-value",
  "createdByAppId": "createdByAppId-value",
  "links": {
    "oneNoteClientUrl": {
      "href": "href-value"
    },
    "oneNoteWebUrl": {
      "href": "href-value"
    }
  },
  "contentUrl": "contentUrl-value",
  "content": "content-value",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2016-10-19T10:37:00Z"
}
```

You can find the full details in their OneNote REST API documentation at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/page-get?view=graph-rest-1.0.

OneNote notebooks and sections also have a "lastModifiedDateTime".

You can use Python to parse the response for the "lastModifiedDateTime" field. See the two pages below for guidance on parsing API responses with Python.

[Selecting fields from JSON output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934699/selecting-fields-from-json-output)

[What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877422/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-a-json-response-from-the-requests-library)

Best of luck with the rest of your project!