# Parse json fields to variables

Tags: python, arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse fields of a json output from an API query.

Example json:

```
{
   "_id":"611a7b651571d300074b9875",
   "Details":{
      "Source":{
         "Type":"WHOIS servers",
         "URL":"http://tiktea.com.au",
         "NetworkType":"ClearWeb"
      },
      "Type":"Phishing",
      "SubType":"RegisteredSuspiciousDomain",
      "Severity":"Medium"
   },
   "Assignees":[
      
   ],
   "FoundDate":"2021-08-16T14:51:17.747Z",
   "Assets":[
      {
         "Type":"Domains",
         "Value":"iktea.net"
      }
   ],
   "TakedownStatus":"NotSent",
   "IsFlagged":false,
   "Closed":{
      "IsClosed":false
   }
}
```

I want to parse some fields, and get something like:

```
URL: http://tiktea.com.au
FoundDate: 2021-08-16T14:51:17.747Z"
```

so I tried this, but didn't work: [Selecting fields from JSON output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934699/selecting-fields-from-json-output)

This is my python code:

```
import requests
import json


#UserID + Api Key
auth = ('USERID','APIKEY')
headers = {    'Content-Type': "application/json",    }


url = "https://api.intsights.com/public/v1/data/alerts/alerts-list?alertType=Phishing
alerts = requests.request("GET", url, auth = auth, headers=headers)

for alertID in alerts.text.split('","'):
  url = "https://api.intsights.com/public/v1/data/alerts/get-alert/"+alertID #<-----This is the request that extract the JSON
  alertDetails = requests.request("GET", url, auth = auth, headers=headers)
  

  dict = alertDetails.text
  url=dict['Assets'][0]['Value'] #<---------Trying to parse the desired value
  print(url)
```

This is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cefexample.py", line 73, in <module>
    url=dict['Assets'][0]['Value']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**Any suggestion?**

Comment: could you update your question to show what the `alerts` response request looks like?

Comment: @DavidCulbreth the response of 'alerts' is: 
["6132fab73125ec00078e7180","6133790774446400078f665a","6133791144b6650007c6a3f4","61337911c406420008499cb9","61337c8792587f000b68c127"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to parse the JSON that comes as response.

```
data = alertDetails.json() # use convenience method
```

Then access fields you want like a nested dict.

```
url = data['Details']['Source'].get('URL')
print (f'Phishing URL: {url}')
found_date = data.get('FoundDate')
print(f'Found date: {found_date}')
```

This assumes (based on error you show) that `Deatails` and `Source` will always be present, ony `URL` key may be missing. To be on the safe side you can do

```
url = data.get('Details', {}).get('Source', {}).get('URL')
print (f'Phishing URL: {url}')
```

or use try/except:

```
try:
    url = data['Details']['Source']['URL']
except KeyError:
    url = None
print (f'Phishing URL: {url}')
```

Comment: Result: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cefexample.py", line 74, in <module>
    url = data['Details']['Source']['URL']
KeyError: 'URL'```
The strange thing is, with other values it works:

if i use: ```url = data['Details']['Source']['NetworkType']```

It works:```python cefexample.py``` result: ```ClearWeb
2021-02-18T16:02:20.926Z```

Comment: It works with the example data provided. Is it possible that `URL` key is missing for particular response? You can use `dict.get()` method to handle missing keys

Comment: I did: ```data = alertDetails.json()    
    data2=data.get('Details')
    data3=data2.get('Source')
    data4= data3.get('URL')
    print ('Phishing URL: '+str(data4))``` and IT WORKS!! :D
But, as you can see, it is so long. There's a way to do te same but summarized?