# How to get the value of "authorization" from Json using python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop

**I have a Json data, where I want to get the value of "authorization" i.e "OToken
DEDC1071B77800A146B6E8D2530E0429E76520C151B40CC3325D8B
6D9242CBA3A6BFA643E7E5596FBEBAE0F46A1FB1BCD099EBC1F59D
CD82F390B6BC45FCE036F37F7F589BD687A691E1378F1FF432331C
62E7E641E857C8F8A405A4BFE2F01B1EB8F3C69817D45F5DDE9DEE
346ACABA1B7208DECA9E43CCE7AB3761553E23D9CB36A870C1819C
15C7C4B1CFE2802DFD05F651AA537AB81787.4145535F55415431" using python**

```
{
"links":[
{
"method":"GET",
"rel":"self",
"href":"https://www.sampleurl.com/request"

},
{
"headers":{
"authorization":"OToken
DEDC1071B77800A146B6E8D2530E0429E76520C151B40CC3325D8B
6D9242CBA3A6BFA643E7E5596FBEBAE0F46A1FB1BCD099EBC1F59D
CD82F390B6BC45FCE036F37F7F589BD687A691E1378F1FF432331C
62E7E641E857C8F8A405A4BFE2F01B1EB8F3C69817D45F5DDE9DEE
346ACABA1B7208DECA9E43CCE7AB3761553E23D9CB36A870C1819C
15C7C4B1CFE2802DFD05F651AA537AB81787.4145535F55415431"

},

"valid_date":"2020-08-17T15:49:00+0530",
"method":"POST",
"rel":"redirect",
"href":"https://www.billdesk.com/pgi/MerchantPayment/",
"parameters":{
"mercid":"BDMERCID",
"bdorderid":"OAFC19XTFD8TSP"

}
}
]
}
```

Comment: Your json data is missing a closing `]`. Would you like to correct it? You can parse your json using `json` module.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting fields from JSON output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934699/selecting-fields-from-json-output)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

response = YOUR_JSON_STRING

data = json.loads(response)

authorization = data['headers']['authorization']
```